# Replacing layout manager in UITextView using TextKit 1

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, textkit

I have a `UITextView` created in storyboard. The view uses TextKit 1, and I'm trying to replace the `NSLayoutManager`. When calling `.sizeThatFits()` (or any other method requiring layout) on my text view, I'm getting an uncaught exception:

```
*** -[NSLayoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:]: given container does not appear in the list of containers for this NSLayoutManager.
```

[A minimal reproducible example project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlhonr0s6ahpjzp/LayoutManagertest.zip?dl=1).

I'm replacing the layout manager in my text view subclass:

```swift
let layoutManager = MyLayoutManager()
layoutManager.textStorage = self.textStorage        
layoutManager.addTextContainer(self.textContainer)      
self.textContainer.replaceLayoutManager(layoutManager)
// etc.
```

I've tried doing it in multiple places, in both `initWithCoder` and `awakeFromNib`, and made sure the layout manager actually **does** contain the `NSTextContainer`. The crash happens even when using plain `NSLayoutManager`, not a subclass.

When looking at the stack trace, I'm seeing calls to private TextKit 1 methods:
[image]

Before entering `.sizeThatFits()`, the container is included in container array:

```swift
if (layoutManager.textContainers.contains(self.textContainer) {
    // true
}
```

I'm unable to tell from the actual assembly calls if the private methods really use my own layout manager, but `glyphRangeForTextContainer:` in my subclass is **not** called from these methods.

Could it be that somehow the private methods find a remnant of the old layout manager in memory, even if it shouldn't be retained by anything?

This also seems to happen in an empty project when using TextKit 1, so it might be a bug, but I want to rule out my user error first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to override `var layoutManager` (or `-(NSLayoutManager*)layoutManager` in ObjC) in your text view. The getter does **not** return the layout manager associated with the text container, which is a bit weird.

```swift
class TextView:UITextView {
    
    var customLayoutManager:NSLayoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
                
        customLayoutManager.textStorage = self.textStorage
        customLayoutManager.addTextContainer(self.textContainer)
        
        self.textContainer.replaceLayoutManager(customLayoutManager)
    }
    
    override var layoutManager: NSLayoutManager {
        return customLayoutManager
    }
    
}
```